# Regular Expression pattern to match specific characters followed by a number

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to find the regular expression pattern that matches these characters (anywhere)

```
;#
```

followed by a number, followed by an optional

```
;#
```

For example, a pattern that would match any of these

```
;#2

;#27

;#275

;#27;#

;#2;#
```

I plan to use this inside a VBA Excel macro.

Thanks to all in advance.

Steve

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

This regex should do the trick:

```
;#\d+(;#)?
```

Comment: Thank you, I would be grateful if you could please tell me what the two commas and the question mark do ?

Comment: oh, I see, its: ;#\d+(;#)?

Comment: So my only question is what the ? character at the end does. Thank you.

Comment: @user815460 `?` means *zero or one time*.